# Limit of integral expression

Tags: analysis

I would like to evaluate this limit
I have a function $A(x)$ such that it possesses a minimum at $x = x_0$ function and is strictly convex in a neighbourhood of a point $x_0$.
Given a sufficiently small $\epsilon$, two additional numbers $x_{bottom}< x_0$ and $x_{top}>x_0$ are defined by the condition $A(x_{top}) = A(x_{bottom})$. It will be assumed such numbers exists (for example, $A(x)$ can be taken monotonically decreasing (respectively, increasing)  for $x < x_{0}$ (respectively, for $x > x_{0}$).
I want then to understand what value the following limit takes.
$$lim_{x_{top}, x_{down} \to x_0 } \int_{x_{bottom}}^{x_{top} } \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{A(x_{top} )– A(x)}}$$
I reasoned as follows.
I expand $A(x)$ in a Taylor series around $x_0$, 
$$ A(x) = A(x_0) + \frac{1}{2} A’’(x_0)  (x-x_0)^2$$
Then, I thought that for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small I could write
$$x_{down} = x_0 - \epsilon, \, \, \,  x_{top} = x_0 + \epsilon$$ because of $A$’s convexity and Taylor series expansion.
Then I rewrite the integral as 
$$\int_{x_0 - \epsilon}^{x_0 + \epsilon} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{ A(x_0) + \frac{1}{2} A’’(x_0)  (\epsilon)^2   - A(x_0) - \frac{1}{2} A’’(x_0)  (\epsilon)^2}} $$

in order to take the limit for $\epsilon \to 0$.
But it turns out a second order expansion took me nowhere. I know in fact it should be sufficient to prove the limit is finite.

Something is seriously wrong. I thought then to expand $A$ around say $x_{bottom}$, and only then send $x_{bottom} to x_{0}$.
The integral reads

$$\int_{x_{bottom}}^{x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{ A(x_{bottom}) + \frac{1}{2} A’’(x_{bottom})  (x-x_{bottom})^2  - A(x_{bottom}) }} $$

then I take $A''$ ot, but what to do with

$$\int_{x_{bottom}}^{x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{ (x-x_{bottom})  } $$

As $x \to x_{bottom}$?

Thank you for any help. This is bugging me a lot and really need to understand.

Comment: $A(x_{top}) = A(x_{bottom}) $ so are you not dividing by zero in your first integral??

Comment: Edited my mistake out, my apologies

Comment: Edit your second integral accordingly and you will get a divisor in your integral of the form $C\varepsilon \sqrt{1-{{\left( \frac{x-{{x}_{0}}}{\varepsilon } \right)}^{2}}}$ where C is a constant.

Comment: Indeed. Many thanks, very grateful